# How to use a recursive function or a loop to define generations of parents, children, grand children etc in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, recursion

I have a Data frame with columns 'Parent', 'Child', 'FamilyName' which have parents and children.

The data frame looks like, let's call this search_df

| Parent | Child | FamilyName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parent1 | Child1 | Parent1 |
| Parent1 | Child2 | Parent1 |
| Child1 | Grandchild1.1 | Parent1 |
| Child1 | Grandchild1.2 | Parent1 |
| Child2 | Grandchild2.1 | Parent1 |
| Child2 | Grandchild2.2 | Parent1 |

and so on (if the dataframe is not clearly visible, I have the image on this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EqjEHyLUgbInsWRgYQBtb15Vzjdo3w0I/view?usp=sharing)

I want to add a new column called "GENERATION" to represent the generation the child-items are from, but I want to do it in a loop as I don't know how many generations would be there in a particular family.

So far I have been able to do this: (For clarity, df1 is the dataset, and search_df is the dataframe generated after using filter of a said FamilyName; FamilyName is essentially the name of the first ever parent in that family)

`parentlist = df1[df1['Parent'].isin (search_df.FamilyName)]`
`parentlist["GENERATION"] = 'Gen2'`

`childlist1 =  df1[df1['Parent'].isin (parentlist.Child)]`
`childlist1["GENERATION"] = 'Gen3'`

`childlist2 =  df1[df1['Parent'].isin (childlist1.Child)]`
`childlist2["GENERATION"] = 'Gen4'`

Now, the problem is we can have n number of childlists, and manually coding it is not going to cut it. So I want to have a loop or a recursive function to generate the childlist dataframes once the parentlist dataframe is generated by the existing code. I can then concat the parentlist dataframe and the childlist dataframes. Essentially I want to loop the part of childlist1, childlist2 and so on and also tag a new column saying gen3, gen4 for their generations until an empty dataframe is generated, i.e., no more children can be found.

The final Dataframe should look something like this

| Parent | Child | FamilyName | Generation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parent1 | Child1 | Parent1 | Gen2 |
| Parent1 | Child2 | Parent1 | Gen2 |
| Child1 | Grandchild1.1 | Parent1 | Gen3 |
| Child1 | Grandchild1.2 | Parent1 | Gen3 |
| Child2 | Grandchild2.1 | Parent1 | Gen3 |
| Child2 | Grandchild2.2 | Parent1 | Gen3 |

Please help, I am very new to python and any help would be highly appreciated. Please feel free to ask more questions in comments if you need any more details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question is not clear. Please try to show exactly *what the output should be* for this input. Do you want to modify the DataFrame? Do you want to create a new one? Do you want to create something else? Just what? It sounded to me like you wanted to modify the DataFrame, by adding an extra column. Can you show exactly what should be in that column, for this input?

Comment: I want to modify the dataframe (But creating a new one works as well). So the dataframe will have one additional column called 'GENERATION'. The generation column will give the generation that the child was in i.e., gen2, gen3, gen4 etc. I have edited the question for the output I want.

Answer (score 0):

I added another family as example:

```
df_tagged = pd.concat([df, df.replace({'Parent1':'Parent2'})])

print(df)
```

```
    Parent          Child FamilyName
0  Parent1         Child1    Parent1
1  Parent1         Child2    Parent1
2   Child1  Grandchild1.1    Parent1
3   Child1  Grandchild1.2    Parent1
4   Child2  Grandchild2.1    Parent1
5   Child2  Grandchild2.2    Parent1
0  Parent2         Child1    Parent2
1  Parent2         Child2    Parent2
2   Child1  Grandchild1.1    Parent2
3   Child1  Grandchild1.2    Parent2
4   Child2  Grandchild2.1    Parent2
5   Child2  Grandchild2.2    Parent2
```

With recursion:

```
df_tagged = df.set_index(['FamilyName', 'Parent']).sort_index()

def tag_row(df, family, parent, level):
    df.loc[(family, parent), 'Generation'] = f'Gen{level}'
    children = df.loc[(family, parent), 'Child']

    for child in children:
        if (family, child) in df.index:
            tag_row(df, family, child, level+1)


df_tagged['Generation'] = ''
for family in df_tagged.index.unique(level='FamilyName'):
    tag_row(df_tagged, family, family, 2)

print(df_tagged)
```

```
                 Child FamilyName Generation
Parent                                      
Parent1         Child1    Parent1       Gen2
Parent1         Child2    Parent1       Gen2
Child1   Grandchild1.1    Parent1       Gen3
Child1   Grandchild1.2    Parent1       Gen3
Child2   Grandchild2.1    Parent1       Gen3
Child2   Grandchild2.2    Parent1       Gen3
Parent2         Child1    Parent2       Gen2
Parent2         Child2    Parent2       Gen2
Child1   Grandchild1.1    Parent2       Gen3
Child1   Grandchild1.2    Parent2       Gen3
Child2   Grandchild2.1    Parent2       Gen3
Child2   Grandchild2.2    Parent2       Gen3
```

Comment: Tried doing this, it gives TypeError: Input must be index or array-like. I can't figure out why :(

Comment: The error is in df_result line BTW

Comment: @New_Noob please check my edit, I added `[parent]` instead of `parent` at the `children = ` line

Comment: Hey, this seems to work but only gives the last instance of the last generation. Any way I could get all the instances?

Comment: @New_Noob so if you run it with the test set you provided in your question you only get one row?

Comment: Not in the test set, but for other "FamilyName" rows.

Comment: @New_Noob I edited the answer with another solution that does not use `groupby`. Try with this one and please note the `df_tagged = df.set_index(['FamilyName', 'Parent']).sort_index()` (first line)

Comment: Hey, this is giving an error - TypeError: 'numpy.float64 object is not iterable. 

Maybe I am unable to explain stuff properly, is there any way we can meet online so I can show you the actual dataset and the problem I am working with to give you a better idea of this?

Comment: Hey, managed to get the error resolved, but I am still getting only the last instance

Comment: @New_Noob you don't have enough reputation to chat on StackOverflow. Contact me [on Telegram](https://t.me/malcapit) and then we can take it up from there.